# tilde in superscript creates unnecessary spaces

Tags: sharelatex, tilde

I am using tile in math mode but it creates some unnecessary spaces over the variable I am using in superscript mode.

```
x^{\sim}
```

Comment: Can you give a compileable example of it creating unnecessary space over the variable?  It is not exactly  clear what you are referring to.  Is it that you want the `\sim` directly over the variable, or that you want it as a superscript but in some cases (yet to be described) it produces unwanted blank space?

Comment: \[ m= x^{\sim}_(_n_+_1_)_/_2\]

Comment: Steven yes you are right this is what now I am facing

Comment: Are you looking for `\overset{\sim}{x}` rather than `x^{\sim}`?  If so, it requires `amsmath` package.

Comment: that one works fine Steven thank you very much for your help

Comment: Steven can we use this without math mode ? like I also need to the same notation for text

Comment: Are you looking for `\tilde x` or perhaps `\widetilde x`?

Comment: Does it works without math mode ? like for me it does not work

Comment: It is a math mode command; however, you could do this, `$\overset{\sim}{\textrm{x}}$` to make the `x` non-math.  Likewise, if you prefer the look of `\tile` to `\overset{\sim}{}`, then you could use `$\tilde{\textrm{x}}$`

Comment: Do you want to place the tilde above or to the right of `x`?

Comment: Yes,exactly what is the purpose of dollar sign ?

Comment: The dollar sign enters and exits inline math mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing all the different suggestions...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\sim}{x}\tilde x\widetilde x$
versus
$\overset{\sim}{\textrm{x}}\tilde{\textrm{x}}\widetilde{\textrm{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]